# How to go to the next page while crawling using bs4 & selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So what I want to do is generating a car plate dataset by crawling websites and downloading car images then label them.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
def image_downloader(url, folder):
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
    except:
        pass
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    images = soup.find_all('img')
    count = 1
    for image in images:
        link = image['src']
        if link.find('https://iranpelak.com/'):
            pass
        else:
            with open(str(count) + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                im = requests.get(link)
                f.write(im.content)
                print('Writing.. ', str(count))
                count += 1

iranpelak_url = 'https://iranpelak.com/car-search'
image_downloader(iranpelak_url, 'car_images')


page_number = 2
while page_number != 10000:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./chromedriver")
    driver.get("https://iranpelak.com/car-search")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    button = driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_number))
    button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    image_downloader(iranpelak_url, 'car_images')
    page_number += 1
```

The point is, to go to the next pages automatically and download all of the images.
It doesnt work and I dont figure out what I did wrong.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Does it fail to go to the next page? Does it fail to download the images?

Comment: Also going to the next page with your selenium code does not change the URL. The url remains the same no matter what page you're on(the page updates on the browser using javascript). This results in your requests function using the same url every time. 

A solution to this problem would be to get the image URLs instead and then pass those into your function for download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As observed, when the website is opened, there is a `Alert` pop-up `Search Page`.

You need to close the `alert` window to click on other `Elements`.

With below code, it did click on the page numbers without `ElementClickInterceptedException`. Handling that pop-up in a `try-except` block, incase if there is no `alert` pop-up.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

page_number = 2
while page_number != 10000:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path to chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://iranpelak.com/car-search")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-role='end']"))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    button = driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_number))
    button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    # image_downloader(iranpelak_url, 'car_images')
    page_number += 1
```

Comment: And I see that you have put `driver.get()` inside the while loop. Not sure you want a new browser window each time. Do let me know if that was not intentional.